# override default jsonp callback name in select2

Tags: jquery, json, jsonp, jquery-select2

I have something like the following, using the select2 plugin:

```
$("#thing").select2({
      ajax: {
        url: 'http://someurl.com',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        jsonpCallback: "callback",
        data: function (term, page) {
          // return stuff;
        },
        results: function (data, page) {
          // return stuff;
        }
      }
  });
```

For some reason, I cannot override the name of the default JSONP callback, which ends up being something like "jQuery19108308313677553087_1365803875152" instead of "callback" as I tried to define it with "jsonpCallback".

How do I name the callback as whatever I want?

Answer (score -2):

I am not horribly familiar with Select2 so this might be a long shot.

Try adding one more parameter after `dataType: 'jsonp'`. The parameter you want to add would be `jsonp: 'false'`. This should allow you to override the default callback.